# How to unwrap and serialize java map in java using jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a bean like this

```
class Foo {
    private Map<String, Data> dataMap;
    private String fooFieldOne;
    private String fooFieldTwo;
}

class Data {
    private fieldOne;
    private fieldTwo;
}
```

I want to serialize as Json as like this

```
{
    "key1": {
        "fieldOne": "some value",
        "fieldTwo": "some value"
    },
    "key2": {
        "fieldOne": "some other value",
        "fieldTwo": "some other value"
    },
    "fooFieldOne":"valueone", 
    "fooFieldTwo":"valuetwo" 
}
```

But i am getting result like

```
{
    "dataMap": {
        "key1": {
            "fieldOne": "some value",
            "fieldTwo": "some value"
        },
        "key2": {
            "fieldOne": "some other value",
            "fieldTwo": "some other value"
        }
    },
    "fooFieldOne":"valueone", 
    "fooFieldTwo":"valuetwo" 
}
```

How to ignore dataMap layer in the above json? I'm using java jackson library for this.

Code i tried is

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValueAsString(myFOOObject)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could create a getter for *dataMap* and serialize the *dataMap* instead of the entire `Foo` instance.

```
mapper.writeValueAsString(myFOOObject.getDataMap());
```

Another method is using the `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation. This annotation is available in Jackson 1.9+.

http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonUnwrapped.html

The downside of using this annotation is the inability to use maps as stated in the [answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043587/why-im-not-able-to-unwrapp-and-serialize-java-map-using-jackson-java-library)

Comment: Hi Bart, Thanks you so much for your detailed answer.  But i also have other fields in my bean. Consider Foo is having other fields fooFieldOne, fooFieldTwo along with the map i already have. I want to serialize everything as single object like { "key1": { "fieldOne": "some value", "fieldTwo": "some value" }, "key2": { "fieldOne": "some other value", "fieldTwo": "some other value" }, "fooFieldOne":"valueone", "fooFieldTwo":"valuetwo" }. How can i handle this?

Comment: Updated my answer to include the @JsonUnwrapped annotation.

Answer (score 5):

I found answer - using @JsonAnyGetter annotation with getter for map. To avoid conflicts during deserialization should be used @JsonAnySetter annotation with setter for this map.

Comment: This is the correct answer, as @JsonUnwrapped does not work for maps.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting

```
{ "dataMap": ... }
```

because `Foo` has a **field** called `dataMap` within it. Here the name of the field *cannot be ignored* because it will create **conflicts** if `Foo` had multiple maps, something like

```
class Foo {
private Map<String, Data> dataMap1;
private Map<String, Data> dataMap2;
}
```

now without having the fieldName : in JSON, the JSON doesn't know how to deserialize when it gets some JSON like

```
{
    //belongs to dataMap1
    "key1": {
        "fieldOne": "some value",
        "fieldTwo": "some value"
    },
    "key2": {
        "fieldOne": "some value",
        "fieldTwo": "some value"
    },
    //belongs to dataMap2
    "key3": {
        "fieldOne": "some value",
        "fieldTwo": "some value"
    },
    "key4": {
        "fieldOne": "some other value",
        "fieldTwo": "some other value"
    }
}
```

Now having the fieldName makes it **very clear** while deserializing

```
{
    "dataMap1" : {
    "key1": {
        "fieldOne": "some value",
        "fieldTwo": "some value"
    },
    "key2": {
        "fieldOne": "some value",
        "fieldTwo": "some value"
    }
    },
    "dataMap2" : {
    "key3": {
        "fieldOne": "some value",
        "fieldTwo": "some value"
    },
    "key4": {
        "fieldOne": "some other value",
        "fieldTwo": "some other value"
    }
  }
}
```

Having said that

> How to ignore dataMap layer in the json?

You can just serialize the map

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValueAsString(myFOOObject.getDataMap());
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your detailed answer. I can understand whats is happening in my case. But i have other fields in my bean. Consider Foo  is having other fields fooFieldOne, fooFieldTwo along with the map i have. I want to serialize everything as single object like {
    "key1": {
        "fieldOne": "some value",
        "fieldTwo": "some value"
    },
    "key2": {
        "fieldOne": "some other value",
        "fieldTwo": "some other value"
    }, "fooFieldOne":"valueone", "fooFieldTwo":"valuetwo"
}. How can i handle this?

Comment: I think its not possible because the map field will always have some name (we cant have unnamed field) and it will surely be captured in JSON

Comment: @sanbhat It is possible using `@JsonUnwrapped`.

Answer (score 0):

In map there is two Objects `String` and `Data` . JSON convert the java objects into JSON key value pair , but if you already have a Map that contain key value pair, and convert that map into JSON document , then map key is also convert into JSON key value pair and Map value also have a object that convert into key value pair.