# Why I'm not able to unwrap and serialize a Java map using the Jackson Java library?

Tags: java, json, jackson

My bean looks like this:

```
class MyBean {

    private @JsonUnwrapped HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    private String name;

    public HashMap<String, String> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(HashMap<String, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

While I'm serializing the bean using the following code:

```
MyBean bean = new MyBean();
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();;
map.put("key1", "value1");
map.put("key2", "value2");
bean.setMap(map);
bean.setName("suren");
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println("\n"+mapper.writeValueAsString(bean));
```

I'm getting result like this:

```
{"map":{"key2":"value2","key1":"value1"},"name":"suren"}
```

but

```
{"key2":"value2","key1":"value1","name":"suren"}
```

is expected per the [JacksonFeatureUnwrapping documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureUnwrapping). Why am I not getting the unwrapped result?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

`@JsonUnwrapped` doesn't work for maps, only for proper POJOs with getters and setters. For maps, You should use [`@JsonAnyGetter`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.6.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonAnyGetter.html) and [`@JsonAnySetter`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.6.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonAnySetter.html) (available in jackson version >= 1.6).

In your case, try this:

```
@JsonAnySetter 
public void add(String key, String value) {
    map.put(key, value);
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String,String> getMap() {
    return map;
}
```

That way, you can also directly add properties to the map, like `add('abc','xyz')` will add a new key `abc` to the map with value `xyz`.

Comment: One may also want to prevent the internal map itself from being serialized in which case `@JsonIgnore` should be applied.

Comment: Adding \@JsonIgnore to the same method marked as \@JsonAnyGetter doesn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: This approach was suggested in a 2011 blog post by the Jackson author, so it's pretty authoritative: http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html

Answer (score 26):

`@JsonUnwrapped` is not supported for `Map` values, and is not planned to be supported.  The officially recommended approach is to use `@JsonAnySetter`/`@JsonAnyGetter` as also proposed in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18043785/770254):

```java
@JsonAnySetter 
public void add(String key, String value) {
    map.put(key, value);
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String,String> getMap() {
    return map;
}
```

## Details

There is an [issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/171) in the Jackson project, created in 2013, to allow support for `@JsonUnwrapped` on maps.  This issue was closed as "will not fix" in 2023, recommending the use of `@JsonAnyGetter` instead:

> Although there may be some aspects where `@JsonAnyGetter` won't work -- f.ex, inability to use more than 1 per POJO -- I think it has big enough overlap that I will close this issue as "wont-fix" (allowing multiple `@JsonAnyGetter`s is a possibility if someone has time to work on doing that).

Other relevant comments in the same issue by the project author:

> as per this:
>
> http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html
>
> one can use @JsonAnyGetter/setter to do something possibly similar. One missing pieces is that currently one must have getter (can't use it on Map filed), but that should be easy enough to address.

> Thinking about this more I think that as things are, it really SHOULD be possible to just use `@JsonAnyGetter` and `@JsonAnySetter` combo to achieve the same result as non-prefixed `@JsonUnwrapped`, wrt `Map`s.
> `@JsonAnySetter` also works for `JsonNode` (although `@JsonAnyGetter not yet, see [#3604](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/3604)).
> Both annotations can be used on fields and methods and you only need to annotate one of the accessors (setter OR getter, not both).
>
> Because of this, I am leaning towards closing this as "will-not-fix". But will not do that quite as yet.
>
> Note, too, that it is perfectly possible to add features (like use of "prefix") to `@JsonAnyGetter`/`@JsonAnySetter`.

Comment: @JsonUnwrapped on member variable fixed my issue. Great answer. Upvoted