# Can I push jackson-mapped @JsonProperties to the "top level"?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Given a Java class like the following:

```
class MyClass {

    String value;

    Map<String,Object> map;

    @JsonProperty("value")
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @JsonProperty("map")
    public Map<String,Object> getMap {
        return map;
    }
}
```

Jackson will convert to JSON like so:

```
{
    "value": "abc",
    "map": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"
    }

}
```

What I would like instead is to "flatten" the `map` attribute somehow so its contents appears at the "top-level" of the JSON structure like this:

```
{
    "value": "abc",
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
}
```

Is that possible *declaratively* through any combinations of Jackson annotations?

(This is a simplification of my actual problem, so I am not looking for an answer like "write your own custom MyClass serializer." In reality, this class must work with custom ObjectMappers in a scenario out of my direct control.)

Comment: `@JsonAnyGetter` works (as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18043785/58530).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why i'm not able to unwrapp and serialize java map using jackson java library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043587/why-im-not-able-to-unwrapp-and-serialize-java-map-using-jackson-java-library)

Answer (score 5):

you can try @JsonUnwrapped

As per [link](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations), this is supposed to remove a layer of wrapping.

(Jackson 1.9+) @JsonUnwrapped (property; i.e method, field) Properties that are marked with this annotation will be "unwrapped", that is, properties that would normally be written as properties of a child JSON Object are instead added as properties of enclosing JSON Object.

Comment: `@JsonUnwrapped` doesn't work for maps, only for proper POJOs with getters and setters. For maps, You should use `@JsonAnyGetter` and `@JsonAnySetter` (available in jackson version >= 1.6). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18043785/293933