# Don't show the map entry in a JSON

Tags: json, spring, rest

I have the following endpoint:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/info")
public class InfoEndPoint {

....

    @Autowired
    public InfoEndPoint(....) {
        ....
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Info get(final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        ...
        return info;
    }

}
```

The info object is the following:

```
public class Info {

    private App app;

    public App getApp() { return app; }
    public void setApp(final App app) { this.app = app; }
}

public class App {

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private Map<String, String> map;

    public App() { map = new HashMap<>(); }

    public Map<String, String> getMap() { return map; }
    public void setMap(final Map<String, String> map) { this.map = map; }
}
```

When I call to the rest endpoint, the response is the following:

```
{
  "app": {
    "map": {
      "description": "Unity-web",
      "name": "Unity"
    }
  }
}
```

But, I would like to remove the map entry, and have this response

```
{
  "app": {
    "description": "project",
    "name": "project"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The solution is described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043587/why-im-not-able-to-unwrapp-and-serialize-java-map-using-jackson-java-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is described here [Why I'm not able to unwrap and serialize a Java map using the Jackson Java library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043587/why-im-not-able-to-unwrapp-and-serialize-java-map-using-jackson-java-library).

Basically it involved calling to @JsonAnyGetter