# How to serialize Map as Object properties in JSON using Jackson?

Tags: java, json

I have an Object which has a few properties and a Map of unknown contents. When I serialize it, I would like to flatten the key value pairs from the Map so they appear as properties of `MyObject`. The below code gives something like the first Json. But I would like to to output the second.

```
{  
   "MyObject":{  
      "name":"name",
      "id":"id",
      "other":{  
         "key1":"value1",
         "key2":"value2"
      }
   }
}

{  
   "MyObject":{  
      "name":"name",
      "id":"id",
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":"value2"
   }
}


ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(this);

public class JsonParent {
  private TopLevel topLevel;

  JsonProperty("MyObject")
  public TopLevel getTopLevel() {
     return topLevel;
  }
} 

public class TopLevel {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private HashMap<String, String> other;

  public getId()

  public getName()

  public getOther() 
}
```

Comment: I'm out of votes, but I would've closed as duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043587/why-im-not-able-to-unwrapp-and-serialize-java-map-using-jackson-java-library

Comment: this worked for me, thanks!