# Serializing HashMap in Kafka Streams

Tags: java, hashmap, jackson, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to serialize `HashMap<String, String>` which are some DTO properties that would end up in ElasticSearch index.

I have class like this:

```
class MyDto {
    HashMap<String, String> properties;
}
```

I want that all properties end up directly under the `_source` in ES:

```
_source: {
    "firstPropKey": "firstValue",
    "secondPropKey": "secondVal"
    ...
}
```

and NOT this:

```
_source: {
    properties: {
       "firstPropKey": "firstValue",
       "secondPropKey": "secondVal"
       ...
    }
}
```

I tried various implementations but can't make it work. Here is one approach:

```
final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

builder.stream(dataTopicName, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), dtoSerde))
    .map((key, myDTO) -> new KeyValue<>(id, myDTO.properties))
    .to(elasticIndexTopicName, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), dtoPropsSerde));
```

The problem is that `dto.properties` is `HashMap` parametrized with `<String, String>` and `Jackson2Serde` does not allow parametrized classes so I need to make it like this:

```
private final Jackson2Serde<HashMap> dtoPropsSerde = new Jackson2Serde<>(mapper, HashMap.class);
```

But then I get type error, more concretely: `Cannot resolve method to(String, Produced<K,V>)`

If I make `dto.properties` old unparametrized HashMap, still doesn't work. Can't find anything useful in my logs.
What am I missing?

EDIT: It is worth noting that I don't get anything in `elasticIndexTopicName` topic which ElasticSearch sink connect is reading.

Comment: Try changing map name from  `properties` to `_source`

Comment: I think I would have then "_source" : { "_source": {...} }

Comment: Can you add the snippet where you send the JSON to ES? If so, then use `MyDto.getProperties()` , that will give you the correct value.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention that I don't get any data to elasticIndexTopicName. I'll update the question

Comment: Did you try that? `MyDto.getProperties()`

Comment: You are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043587/why-im-not-able-to-unwrap-and-serialize-a-java-map-using-the-jackson-java-libra)

Comment: Ok, I annotated getProperties() with @JsonAnyGetter and used it in map(). Still getting error in to() method. I think dtoPropsSerde is to blame because it uses old HashMap. Anyway, I'm not sure if I need to create new Serde instance and implement all methods because that's the type the to() method is asking for.