# JSON parsing using jackson in spring?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have the following JSON

```
{
  "ads": [
    {
  "228029_228029": {
    "ad_id": "228029",
    "duration": 10,
    "m3u8_text": {
      "_1280p": "#EXTM3U\n#EXT-X-VERSION:3\n#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES\n#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:7\n#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0\n#EXTINF:7.120000,\n_1280p_0000.ts\n#EXTINF:2.880000,\n_1280p_0001.ts\n#EXT-X-ENDLIST\n",
      "_320p": "#EXTM3U\n#EXT-X-VERSION:3\n#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES\n#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:7\n#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0\n#EXTINF:7.120000,\n_320p_0000.ts\n#EXTINF:2.880000,\n_320p_0001.ts\n#EXT-X-ENDLIST\n"
    }
  }
},
{
  "228845_228845": {
    "ad_id": "228845",
    "duration": 24,
    "m3u8_text": {
      "_1280p": "#EXTM3U\n#EXT-X-VERSION:3\n#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES\n#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8\n#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0\n#EXTINF:7.840000,\n_1280p_0000.ts\n#EXTINF:6.880000,\n_1280p_0001.ts\n#EXTINF:6.680000,\n_1280p_0002.ts\n#EXTINF:2.600000,\n_1280p_0003.ts\n#EXT-X-ENDLIST\n",
      "_320p": "#EXTM3U\n#EXT-X-VERSION:3\n#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES\n#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8\n#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0\n#EXTINF:7.840000,\n_320p_0000.ts\n#EXTINF:6.880000,\n_320p_0001.ts\n#EXTINF:6.680000,\n_320p_0002.ts\n#EXTINF:2.600000,\n_320p_0003.ts\n#EXT-X-ENDLIST\n"
    }
  }
}
  ],
  "total_duration": 80
}
```

I have created the respective model class as
This is the root model

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class AdsResponse {
@JsonProperty("ads")
List<Ad> ads;
@JsonProperty("total_duration")
long totalDuration;
}
```

Then the ads model

```
public class Ad {
Map<String,AdInfo> ad;}
```

Then the AdInfo model

```
public class AdInfo {
@JsonProperty("m3u8_text")
AdManifest adManifest;
int duration;
@JsonProperty("ad_id")
String adId;}
```

Then the manifest model

```
public class AdManifest {
@JsonProperty("_1280p")
String _1280p;
@JsonProperty("_320p")
String _320p;}
```

When I try to parse this using below code

```
AdsResponse response = new ObjectMapper().readValue(
                res,
                AdsResponse.class);
```

I get the empy ad object

```
AdsResponse{ads=[Ad{ad=null}, Ad{ad=null}, totalDuration=80}
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Your `Ad` class seems to be missing the proper mapping. It would require an `ad` property to be present in the JSON but your JSON indicates the name of the nested map shouldn't be there. You might need to use the `@JsonAnySetter` etc. annotations to "route" the properties of each "ad" into the `Ad.ad` map. - This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57312679/jackson-hashmap-ignore-map-name-when-writing-to-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need the `Ad` class, it's just a `Map<>`. `AdResponse` can look like this:

```java
public class AdsResponse {

    @JsonProperty("ads")
    List<Map<String, AdInfo>> ads;

    @JsonProperty("total_duration")
    long totalDuration;
```

If the keys in the map were predictable, you could make them properties on the `Ad` class and then Jackson would map them properly. But since they're not (they look like some kind of ID), mapping them to a `Map<>` is probably the best option.

As an alternative, if you want or need to have the `Ad` objects, you can map them like this:

```java
public class Ad {

    Map<String, AdInfo> adInfo = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAds(String key, AdInfo value) {
        adInfo.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

With that, ***and `AdResponse` defined the way you have it in the question***, you'll get populated `Ad` instances, each of which has a `Map<>` with only 1 key/value pair. For an even simpler (and probably more sensible model, you can eliminate the `Map` if there is only ever 1 key in an `Ad`, like this:

```java
public class Ad {

    private AdInfo adInfo;

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdInfo(String ignored, AdInfo value) {
        this.adInfo = value;
    }
}
```