# How to map json from java object dynamically?

Tags: java, json, serialization, java-8, jackson

How can we map the java object to json? Java object will have a map and some other string properties. What I want is that when we convert the java object to json that map keys should be as root key not nested key.

**Sample Java Object :**

```java
class Demo {
    String name;
    String designation;
    Map<String,Object> attribute;
}
```

Now if Map is having values like below :

```java
Map<String,Object> attribute = new HashMap<>();
attribute.put("score",190);
attribute.put("status","allowed");
```

Output should be like below:

```
{
  "name":"jack",
  "designation":"Tester",
  "score":190,
  "status":"allowed"
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html?

Comment: @harshvardhan.agr you got it right... but it is not working in case of Map..

Comment: @NishantVarshney This [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043587/why-im-not-able-to-unwrap-and-serialize-a-java-map-using-the-jackson-java-libra/41833934) shall help you further.

Comment: @NishantVarshney did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043587/why-im-not-able-to-unwrap-and-serialize-a-java-map-using-the-jackson-java-libra/41833934 ?

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right - use Jackson. Example:

**Java Objects to JSON**

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// Java object to JSON file
mapper.writeValue(new File("c:\\test\\staff.json"), new Staff());

// Java object to JSON string
String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
```

**JSON to Java Objects**

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

//JSON file to Java object
Staff obj = mapper.readValue(new File("c:\\test\\staff.json"), Staff.class);

//JSON URL to Java object
Staff obj = mapper.readValue(new URL("http://some-domains/api/name.json"), Staff.class);

//JSON string to Java Object
Staff obj = mapper.readValue("{'name' : 'mkyong'}", Staff.class);
```

Repo: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind

Jackson JSON Tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson

Another example: https://mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Comment: Jackson we can use but what I want is that in the converted json from the map,key should be as root key not inside an object...

Comment: @NishantVarshney then create another deserialization, or add a method to receive the inner object, and put its properties in the parent. Create a placeholder model, and output the object as you want.