# Serialize Map as properties of parent object

Tags: java, json, jackson, annotations

I have a class Parent which has some properties including one Map<String, object>.

```
public class Parent {

  private final int propA;
  private final String propB;
  private final Map<String, Object> map;

  publicParent(int propA, String propB, Map<String, Object> map) {
    this.propA = propA;
    this.propB = propB;
    this.map = map;
  }

  public int getPropA() {
    return propA;
  }

  public String getPropB() {
    return propB;
  }

  public Map<String, Object> getMap() {
    return map;
  }

}
```

When serializing that I'll for instance get this:

```
{
  "propA": 5,
  "propB": "foo",
  "map": {
    "bar": "bong",
    "bing": "bang"
  }
}
```

How can I annotate the class so Jackson will serialize an instance of it placing the map entries as bare properties to the parent object instead?

```
{
  "propA": 5,
  "propB": "foo",
  "bar": "bong",
  "bing": "bang"
}
```

Comment: `@JsonUnwrapped`?

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18043785/4207306 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the `@JsonAnyGetter` annotation to achieve this. There is also a matching `@JsonAnySetter` annotation that does the opposite: stuff unrecognized properties in a map.

```
  @JsonAnyGetter
  public Map<String, Object> getMap() {
    return map;
  }
```

Here's a helpful guide: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations