# Unwrap config settings during the serialisation

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson

I try to make config manager for my app. I have some problems with `Jackson`. Here is my object mapper config:

```kotlin
val mapper = ObjectMapper()

val jackson = mapper.setVisibility(
        mapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
            .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
    )
    .configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_SELF_REFERENCES, false)
    .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
    .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
```

and then we saving arraylist of modules.every module has

```
@JsonProperty("config")  public ArrayList<SettingAbstract> settings = new ArrayList<SettingAbstract>( );
```

SettingAbstract have name and value. i did this

```
@JsonProperty("property") public abstract String saveCfg();
```

and then this in SettingAbstract child classes

```
    @Override
    public String saveCfg() {
        return this.name + ": " + this.value;
    }
```

The result `JSON` is:

```
..., {
  "enabled" : false,
  "name" : "ESP",
  "config" : [ {
    "property" : "Players: true"
  }, {
    "property" : "Mobs: false"
  }, {
    "property" : "Hostiles: false"
  } ],
  "currentSettingsPage" : 0
}, {
  "enabled" : false,
  "name" : "Custom Time",
  "config" : [ {
    "property" : "Ticks: 19000"
  } ],
  "currentSettingsPage" : 0
}, ...
```

What I want is:

```
..., {
  "enabled" : false,
  "name" : "ESP",
  "Players": true",
  "Mobs": "false",
  "Hostiles": "false",
  "currentSettingsPage" : 0
}, {
  "enabled" : false,
  "name" : "Custom Time",
  "Ticks": "19000",
  "currentSettingsPage" : 0
}, ...
```

Main problems:

1. how to remove theese [] <- from arraylist
2. how to remove {} <- from SettingAbstract class (because im saving only 1 property)
3. and how to save key as setting name (various modules has various settings)

Comment: Convert list to `Map` and use `@JsonAnyGetter` annotation. See also: [Why I'm not able to unwrap and serialize a Java map using the Jackson Java library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043587/why-im-not-able-to-unwrap-and-serialize-a-java-map-using-the-jackson-java-libra)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unwrap `config` property. It is a list, so you need to ignore it and add extra method which converts that list to `Map`. In `Kotlin` it could look like this:

```kotlin
@JsonAnyGetter
fun getSettingsAsMap(): Map<String, String>? {
   return settings.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(SettingAbstract::name, SettingAbstract::value));
}
```

And you need to ignore list:

```java
@JsonIgnore public ArrayList<SettingAbstract> settings
```